# insert array to empty array in for-loop javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an empty array & want to insert all the arrays returned from the query from mongodb in for loop, but data is not push into the arr. Below is the code :

```
  var arr = [];
   categoryObj.find({is_deleted:false,ancestors: []}, function(err, data) {
       if(data) {

           for (i=0;i< data.length;i++) {
               categoryObj.find({is_deleted:false}, function(err, result) {
                  if (result) {
                      arr[i].push(result);
                  }
              })
          }
       }
 console.log(arr);
}
```

Any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `categoryObj.find` doing?

Comment: categoryObj is the model in mongodb, from which i am retrieving data

Comment: This can be because, you are making a async call and running loop before receiving response. Try Promise or callback function in that case.

Comment: If the function in arguments will ever be called, `arr[i].push()` probably causes an error. `push` is the method to create `[i]`, you should not hard code it.

Comment: do you get your data as an Object or an Array? Could you post/add a example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    const data = await categoryObj.find({is_deleted:false,ancestors: []});
    const arr = await Promise.all(data.map(async (item) => {
        const children = await categoryObj.find({is_deleted:false, ancestors: {
            $in: [item._id]
        }});
        return children;
    });
    console.log(arr);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If *result* isn't empty then a simple **arr.push(result)** should do the thing (without [i]) Otherwise you should check if result isn't returning anything by outputting it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [];

   for (i=0;i< data.length;i++) {
        categoryObj.find({is_deleted:false}, function(err, result) {
           if (result) {
                arr.push(result);
           }
        })
   }
 console.log(arr);
```

Do `arr.push` instead of `arr[i].push`.

Comment: Try doing consol.log(data) on the top and tell me the output of console.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is an object you have to use this code:

```
for(var key in data){
    var value = data[key];
    /* do something with your data, e.g. arr.push(value); */
}
```

If your data is an array you could use your code but change this line

```
arr[i].push(result);
```

to

```
arr.push(result);
```

Comment: I have used that, but still get blank array.

Comment: the object-way or the array-way? What kind of return value do you get from mongoDB? Could you please post it.